# ggplot2 for intra-day financial data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have intra-day trade data which I'm trying to plot using `ggplot`.

For a given day, the data looks as such (for example)…

```
head(q1)
time  last   bid   ask volume center
1 2014-03-19 09:30:00.480 63.74 63.39 63.74    200     11
2 2014-03-19 09:30:00.645 63.41 63.41 63.60    100     11
3 2014-03-19 09:30:00.645 63.48 63.41 63.60    100     11
4 2014-03-19 09:30:02.792 63.59 63.44 63.60    100     11
5 2014-03-19 09:30:03.023 63.74 63.44 63.75    100     12
6 2014-03-19 09:30:12.987 63.72 63.44 63.76    100     11

tail(q1)
time  last   bid   ask volume center
2116 2014-03-19 15:59:56.266 61.68 61.67 61.74    168     12
2117 2014-03-19 15:59:58.515 61.68 61.68 61.73    100     28
2118 2014-03-19 15:59:59.109 61.69 61.68 61.73    500     11
2119 2014-03-19 16:00:00.411 61.72 61.69 61.73    100     11
2120 2014-03-19 16:00:00.411 61.72 61.69 61.73    200     11
2121 2014-03-19 16:00:00.411 61.72 61.69 61.73    351     11
```

It's easy to use `gglot` to visualize a single day of data, where I'm having trouble is linking multiple days together on the same plot. If I have 2 consecutive days in the data frames `q1` & `q2`, how can I plot these on a single plot without the time gap when the market is closed and the lines linking the end of one day to another?

Comment: have you tried a facet plot by day?

Comment: Hi, I did consider that, but I really want the data to have the same y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new transformation that transforms day time to a seamless scale of trading time:

```
 9:30          -> 0
12:00          -> approx. 0.5
16:00          -> 1
 9:30 next day -> 1
```

Something along the following lines could do (but I haven't tried myself):

```
library(scales)
trading_day_trans <- function() {
    trans_new("trading_day", trans, inv,
              pretty_breaks(), domain = domain)
}

ggplot(rbind.fill(q1, q2)) + ... + coord_trans(xtrans = "trading_day")
```

You need to provide `trans` (the transformation function, time -> linear), `inv` (the inverse transform, linear -> time) and `domain` (a time vector of length 2, min-max).

Adapted from http://blog.ggplot2.org/post/25938265813/defining-a-new-transformation-for-ggplot2-scales .

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution, however, I would really like to be able to keep the time markings if possible.

Comment: @Craig: What happens to the time markings with my sketch? Could you please update your question or ask a new one?

Comment: Seems pretty obvious to me reading your link that the original markings are not preserved. I'm not sure I can phrase the question any differently.

Comment: @Craig: No, it's not obvious to me. What do you mean by *markings*? Have you even tried to implement my suggestion?